# Pinging an address shows request timeout

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, debian, ping

I am totally a newbie of Linux trying to remotely log into Debian from OS X via SSH.

After installing OpenSSH on the server, `ssh -vvv ***.***.***.165` gives the following output:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ***.***.***.165 [***.***.***.165] port 22.
ssh: connect to host address port 22: Operation timed out
```

and then I tried `ping address` giving:

```
PING ***.***.***.165 (***.***.***.165): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
.
.
.
--- address ping statistics ---
134 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

I have checked the output of `/sbin/iptables -L` on the server:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Any comment would be appreciated.

EDIT:
`/sbin/ifconfig` outputs:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 38:2c:4a:71:bb:8f  
          inet addr:***.***.***.165  Bcast:***.***.***.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Memory:fb600000-fb620000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 38:2c:4a:71:b7:87  
          inet addr:***.***.***.165  Bcast:***.***.***.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3a2c:4aff:fe71:b787/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2437561 errors:0 dropped:41826 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:112569 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:309632508 (295.2 MiB)  TX bytes:44212568 (42.1 MiB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fb100000-fb120000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:376998 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:376998 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:114274728 (108.9 MiB)  TX bytes:114274728 (108.9 MiB)
```

sorry I have to mask the ip and the `***.***.***` above stands for the same thing.

UPDATE:

I successfully SSH after connecting my local computer to other Wifi. 
There are many PCs (including the server) connected to the internet through the same router (wired or wireless). And my local computer is connected wirelessly. Once I switch the Wifi to the other, the SSH works.

How do I fix the problem if I want to go back to the original Wifi?

Comment: If it's a remote system there can be any number of firewalls beteween you and it. Try tools like `traceroute` and `mtr`

Comment: I'm speculating your remote Debian server is either behind a NAT router or a firewall. What's the output of `ifconfig`?

Comment: @geewee I just added the output in the OP.

Comment: Your case is weird. Check if: 1) you can SSH into the server from itself, 2) you can ping the network interface and localhost from the server itself, 3) SELinux is installed and enabled (turn it off or uninstall if it is). If the first two checks are positive and the last one is negative, there's most likely something outside of the server that's getting in the way (could be anything; firewall and routing issue most of the time).

Comment: You are right, I think it is about the router. Please see my update. And sorry for the wording, I am not good with these network or command line stuff.